# VS2017, out of memory exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, out-of-memory

I have a C# Asp.net Web Application that uses lots of data, and at some point I get System.OutOfMemory exception despite the fact that the application is using only around 4GB of RAM and I have 32GB of RAM on my computer (of which at least 20 is free).

If I have so much free RAM, why am I getting this exception? Is there any way to increase the memory limit?

Thanks in advance

EDIT

Guys, thanks very much for trying to help me - I have read both articles but I still don't understand - is it really not possible to somehow solve this problem? Does this mean that basically whatever I am developing on C#, I cannot possibly use more than 4GB? I am sure there is a way round this?

Comment: Please include a screenshot of your Application Pool -> Advanced Settings (in IIS).

Comment: please correct the title for god's sake this question has nothing to do with VisualStudio2017

Comment: With web app consuming 4GB memory, it is about the time to reconsider the overall architecture

Comment: @Ondra there are some scenarios where that would be absolutely valid, and there are scenarios where that would suggest a major problem. We don't know enough to guess which.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a 32-bit .NET app then you're limited to 4G by the address space. [Details here.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483475/Memory-Limits-in-a-NET-Process)

With 32G of RAM you can have lots of 4G apps running at the same time. But each individual app is limited to 4G.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a 32 bit application, then it'll only be able to address 4gb of memory, regardless of how much more physical memory you have. This article explains the situation well: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory/.

P.s. you could have gotten the info you needed with a quick SO search. Look through existing posts before posting next time :)